# how to restructure data from h5py written in python

Tags: python, h5py

[image]I am reading functions from an existing file using h5py library.

```
readFile = h5py.File('File',r)
```

using `readFile.keys()` I obtained the list of the functions stored in 'File'. One of these functions is the function phi. To print the function phi, I did

```
phi = numpy.array(readFile['phi'])[:,0,:,:]
```

in [:,0,:,:] we find the way how the data is stored [blocks, z, y, x]. z= 0 because it is a 2D case. x is divided in 2 blocks, and y is divided to 2 blocks. each x block is divided to nxb (x1, x2, ....,x20), and each y block is divided to nyb. (nxb and nyb can also be obtained directly from the file using h5py as they are also stored in the file. The domain of the data is also stored in the file and it is called ['bounding box'])

Then , coding the grid will be:

```
nxb = numpy.array(readFile['integer scalars'])[0][1]
nyb = numpy.array(readFile['integer scalars'])[1][1]
X = numpy.zeros([block, nxb, nyb])
Y = numpy.zeros([block, nxb, nyb])
for block in range(block):
    x_min, x_max = numpy.array(readFile['bounding box'])[block,0,:]
    y_min, y_max = numpy.array(readFile['bounding box'])[block,1,:]
    X[block,:,:], Y[block,:,:] = numpy.meshgrid(numpy.linspace(x_min,x_max,nxb), 
                                                numpy.linspace(y_min,y_max,nyb))
```

My question, is that I am trying to restructure the data (see the figure). I want to bring the data of the block 2 up to the data of the block 1 and not next to him. Which means that I need to create new coordinates I' and J' related to the old coordinates I , and J. I tried this but it is not working:

```
for i in range(X):
    for j in range(Y):
        i' = i -len(X[0:1,:,:]
        j' = j + len(Y[0:1,:,:]
        phi(i',j') = phi
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with HDF5 data, it's important to understand your data schema before you start writing code. Here are my initial observations and suggestions.

Your question is a little hard to follow. (For example, you are using the term  "functions" to describe HDF5 datasets.) HDF5 organizes data in datasets and groups. Your data of interest is in 2 datasets: `'phi'` and `'integer scalars'`.

You can simplify code to access the datasets as a Numpy arrays using the following:

```
with h5py.File('File','r') as readFile:
    # to get the axis dimensions for 'phi':
    print(f"Shape of Dataset phi: {readFile['phi'].shape}")
    phi_ds = readFile['phi']  # to get a dataset object
    phi_arr = readFile['phi'][()]  # to read dataset as a numpy array

    # to get the axis dimensions for 'integer scalars'
    nxb, nyb = readFile['integer scalars'].shape
```

I don't understand what you mean by "blocks". Are you referering to the axis simensions? Also, why you are using `meshgrid`? If you simply want to change dimensions, use Numpy's `.reshape()` method to change the axis dimensions of the Numpy array.

Here is a simple example that creates a 2x2 dataset, then reads it into a new array and reshapes it to 1x4. I think this is what you want to do. Change the values of a0 and a1 if you want to increase the size. The reshape operation will read the shape from the first array and reshape the new array to `(N,1)`, where N is your `nxb*nyb` value.

```
with h5py.File('SO_72340647.h5','w') as h5f:
    a0, a1 = 2,2
    arr = np.arange(a0*a1).reshape(a0,a1)
    h5f.create_dataset('ds_2x2',data=arr)

with h5py.File('SO_72340647.h5','r') as h5f:
    print(f"Shape of Dataset ds_2x2: {h5f['ds_2x2'].shape}")
    ds_arr = h5f['ds_2x2'][()]
    print(ds_arr)
    ds0, ds1 = ds_arr.shape
    new_arr = ds_arr.reshape(ds0*ds1,1)
    print(f"Shape of new (reshaped) array: {new_arr.shape}")
    print(new_arr)
```

Note: h5py dataset objects "behave like" Numpy arrays. So, you frequently don't have to read into an array to use the data.